# Writing to csv file getting an array out of bounds error

Tags: java, string, csv

I want to write anything that is in arraylist irrespective of its size in this manner in the csv but one array has less values it causes an array out of bounds error is there any way to work around this?

In this A to H it has it's own arraylist, sometimes the other arrays have less elements in it than size of A this causes array out of bounds.

```
try{
        File file = new File("aaaa.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    
        for(int j=0;j<A.size();j++) {
            bw.write(A.get(j));
            bw.write(","+B.get(j));
            bw.write(","+C.get(j));
            bw.write(","+D.get(j));
            bw.write(","+E.get(j));
            bw.write(","+F.get(j));
            bw.write(","+G.get(j));
            bw.write(","+H.get(j));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
         
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *In this A to H it has it's own arraylist* Out of interest - why?

Comment: It basically is extracting info from a file based on specific topic storing into its specific arraylist

Comment: If A-H have come from one file, this has an aroma of something being done in the wrong way ;) (On the basic of the old saying *data that belong together should **be** together*)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare a list size with the current value of the index *j*

```java
for (int j = 0; j < A.size(); j++) {  
  bw.write(A.get(j));  
  bw.write("," + (B.size() > j ? B.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (C.size() > j ? C.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (D.size() > j ? D.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (E.size() > j ? E.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (F.size() > j ? F.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (G.size() > j ? G.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.write("," + (H.size() > j ? H.get(j) : ""));  
  bw.newLine();  
}
```